# Why does 'mount' refuse to make a directory?

Tags: linux, mount

I know that by default, perhaps creating a directory would be a bad idea. However, I believe there isn't any reason not to allow [mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(Unix)) to create directories with an option.

Is there a reason for the missing feature, or has it simply not been implemented yet?

Comment: It [works under Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks) (I tried it on the Arch Linux-derived [ArcoLinux](https://arcolinux.info/) ([version 23.03.01](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2023/03/02/arcolinux-information-confusion/), 2023-03-01)). The example from the former is `mount --mkdir /dev/sr0 /mnt/repo`

Comment: It may not be tied to a particular Linux distribution, just a version(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mount` doesn't create directories, because that's not its job. There isn't any need for it to do so; it's not a missing feature.

If you're going to ask for such a feature, then you need to think about the behaviour as well... For example, does it work like `mkdir` or like `mkdir -p`? At this point, it's easier to just use `mkdir` in the occasional scenario that you want to make a directory.

Comment: I was going to write an answer like this ("do one thing and do it well") but then I realized `mount` nowadays can create loop devices. It works like `losetup` when it needs to, despite "that's not its job".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski agreed, though I think that line is a little more blurry, as automating `losetup` allows you to `mount` filesystem images (rather than just block devices) with a single command, which is only a small extension of its purview. Tough to call...

Comment: I think we are better off with mount creating its directories (`--mkdir`). This creates some nice guarantees such as directory exists only if the mount was successful. It does not need sophisticated options, and when you think about designing it you should not worry about giving it every feature but it is necessary to know and understand what you want out of it.

Answer (score 18):

In Linux, you can tell `mount` to create the target directory using an option (`x-mount.mkdir`). For example,

```
mount /dev/sdb1 -t ext4 -o rw,x-mount.mkdir /newdir/mntpoint
```

tells `mount` to create `/newdir/mntpoint` if it does not exist. The behavior is identical to `mkdir -p`, so if `/newdir` doesn't exist, it will create it for you. If either `/newdir` or `/newdir/mntpoint` exists, it will *not* fail—it creates directories as needed.

Comment: This doesn't work on my system...

Comment: FYI, I thought that the `.` between x-mount and mkdir was supposed to be a `,`  - but it's not.

Comment: manual says the x should be uppercase i.e. `X-mount.mkdir`, dunno if that matters

Comment: @xeruf: Covered in [Marcin Depa's "answer"](https://superuser.com/questions/1224054/why-does-mount-refuse-to-make-a-directory/1717495#1717495) (though it ought to be converted to a comment).

Answer (score 1):

`mount` from `util-linux` now supports `-m`/`--mkdir` as a shortcut for `X-mount.mkdir` mentioned in few other answers. The option was [implemented in 2021](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=5a72054bd0e4590ed5f17ed862dcfeeb568f1c91).

E.g. in Kubuntu 22.10 there is `util-linux 2.38` from 2022-02-17 and you can use the option:

```
mount -m /dev/something /mountpoint/to/be/created
```

(Note: `umount` later does not remove any directory. The mountpoint will survive `umount`.)

Answer (score 0):

As [Larssend's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1224054/why-does-mount-refuse-to-make-a-directory/1224114#1224114), note that the lowercase option is deprecated. It should be `X-mount.mkdir`

The documentation says:

> The option is also supported as x-mount.mkdir, notation is deprecated
> since v2.30.

Improved command:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 -t ext4 -o rw,X-mount.mkdir /newdir/mntpoint
```